# quadratic equation solving mistake

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm a student who started self learning quadratic equations for a youth university program. I'm busy at trying to solve such equation:

$$
(1 - 4x)^2 + 9x + 7 = 2(x+3)(1-x) + (x+4)^2
$$

this is my current progress:

\begin{align}
(1 - 4x)^2 + 9x + 7 &= 2(x+3)(1-x)+ (x+4)^2\\
(1 - 4x)(1 - 4x) + 9x + 7 &= (2x + 6)(1 - x) + (x + 4)(x + 4)\\
1 - 4x - 4x + 16x^2 + 9x + 7 &= 2x - 2x^2 + 6 - 6x + x^2 + 4x + 4x + 16\\
8 + 16x^2 + x &= 2x - x^2 + 6 - 6x + 8x + 16\\
8 + 16x^2 + x &= 4x - x^2 + 22\\
16x^2 + x &= 4x - x^2 + 14\\
16x^2 &= 3x - x^2 + 14\\
17x^2 &= 3x + 14
\end{align}
The solutions to this equation are $x = 1,~x=-14/17$.
So, where is my mistake? $x$ is negative, so I must be incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think the result must be wrong ? It is correct ! You should however write $x_1=1$ , $x_2=-\frac{14}{17}$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: When you say the solution is $x = 1/(-14/17)$, what do you mean, exactly? If you meant "the solutions are $x = 1$ or $x = -14/17$", then you should say it that way, as $/$ most commonly means division, and shouldn't be used to signify "or" in math expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working is all fine. Only the last step was remaining to be written down after factoring.

Answer (score 11):

You have not made any mistake.

The final equation you have obtained is
$$17x^2-3x-14=0$$
$$17x^2-17x+14x-14=0$$
$$17x(x-1)+14(x-1)=0$$
$$(17x+14)(x-1)=0$$
which has the roots $1$ and $\frac{-14}{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(1 - 4)^2 + 9 + 7 = 2(1+3)(1-1) + (1+4)^2
$$
seems true ($25$ in both members), and with a little more effort
$$
\left(1 - 4\frac{\overline{14}}{17}\right)^2 + 9\frac{\overline{14}}{17} + 7 = 2\left(\frac{\overline{14}}{17}+3\right)\left(1-\frac{\overline{14}}{17}\right) + \left(\frac{\overline{14}}{17}+4\right)^2
$$
is

$$(17+56)^2-9\cdot17\cdot14+7\cdot17^2=2(-14+51)(17+14)+(-14+68)^2$$which is $5210$ on both sides.

As a quadratic equation has at most two roots, your work is right.